# Splitting String eliminates part of the string Android

Tags: java, android, string, split

After splitting a string in Android it doesn't include some of the split parts.

The code is in a for loop where the SetServerString is changing every iteration, it works for 6 out of 10 elements but for some reason when the string is Switch it wont work, there is a space before the Switch string so I have removed that but still not working.. any suggestions please..

I am trying to split the string so I can get a device name and node number from the string, this is then inserted into a List view and a database.

> SetServerString = " Switch 2:0" // there is a space before the Switch

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeo; i++) {
...

   if(SetServerString.substring(0,1).equals(dashremove)){
   SetServerString=SetServerString.substring(1,SetServerString.length()-1);
    Log.v("NEW", "Contains setset "  +SetServerString + "sixe "+  String.valueOf(SetServerString.length()) );
    }               
        SetServerString = SetServerString.replaceAll("\\W", "-");
            Log.v("NEW", "the name of the device is : " +SetServerString ); // its ok here 

            GWave.Gdevicenameo.add(SetServerString);
            String node = SetServerString; 
            Log.v("NEW", "the name of the node is : " +node );   // still on here
            String string = node;
            String[] parts = string.split("-");                    // disappears here
                    String part1 = parts[0];
                    String part2 = parts[1]; 
                    String part3 = parts[2];
                    String part4 = parts[3];
                    String part5 = parts[4];

String devnamee = part1 + " " + part2 + " " + part3 ;
String devnamee2 = part1 + " " + part2 + " " + part3 + " "+ part4;

Log.v("NEW","node "+ node +" devname1 "+ devnamee2+ " devname2 "+ devnamee2);

.....

else if(devnamee2.contains("Switch")){
                        Log.v("ZZ","I AM HERE SWITCH");

                        String name = devnamee2.substring(devnamee2.length()-2,devnamee2.length()-1);

                        if(name.equals(" "))

                        {
                            devnamee2=devnamee2.substring(0, devnamee2.length()-2);
                            //Log.v("ZZ","NOT " +devnamee2);

                        }

                        devicenamelist.add(devnamee);
                        devicenodelist.add(part3);
                        Log.v("ZZ","NODE LIST  " +part3 +"| Sensor" + part1 + " p2 " + part2 + " p3 " + part3 + " p4 "+ part4 + " p5 "+ part5) ;
                        GWave.Gdevicename.add(SetServerString);
                    }
```

Comment: Can you post the value of node variable?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe if you give us sample inputs and what the eventual output should look like, we could help you come up with a better solution?

Comment: Also, as a suggestion, I would say try following java naming coventions. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Did you double check your regex with a checker like this? https://www.debuggex.com/ or maybe a java regex checker